# Bulk loading with special characters using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, greenplum, bulk-load

I am currently using "copy_from" to do bulk load, but it seems to give error due to the presence of double quotes in the data.

```
engineor = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://xxxx:xxxx@xxxxx:xxxx/?service_name=xxxxx')
sql = "select * from xxxxxx WHERE ROWNUM <= 10"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, engineor)

enginegp = create_engine('xxxxx@xxxxx:xxxx/xxxx')
connection = enginegp.raw_connection()
output = io.StringIO()
df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
output.seek(0)
output.getvalue()
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.copy_from(output, 'test', null="")
connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

The error I am getting is "DataError: missing data for column" with some column name. I tried removing comma from the data using replace, I still get the error with a different column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CSV format instead of trying to fake postgresql TSV format.
Unlike CSV TSV does not use quotes. TSV format requires using C escapes for non-printing characters - if your data conatins any newlines you'll end up what appear to be short rows. if it contains any tabs you'll get long rows.

to do CSV you need to use copy_expert which will grant access to all the options the postgresql copy command supports including CSV support.

```
df.to_csv(output, header=False, index=False)
```

...

```
cur.copy_expert("COPY test FROM STDIN WITH CSV NULL '' ", output)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. Any options to specify schema in this?